# Port forwarding to Ubuntu EC2 server fails, after it succeeded the first time

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, port-forwarding

I am attempting to forward local port 8000 on a Windows 10 machine to port 8888 on a remote Ubuntu server on EC2, so that I can access and edit jupyter notebooks on the server from my local machine. It worked the first time I made the connection, but I've been getting `Forwarded connection refused by server` messages ever since. I'm forwarding the port via PuTTY on the local machine, and the server is running Ubuntu 16.04. Can anyone help me understand why it stopped working?

I configured my jupyter notebook server as described here: https://hackernoon.com/aws-ec2-part-4-starting-a-jupyter-ipython-notebook-server-on-aws-549d87a55ba9

Once jupyter was installed, I started the notebook server with the following command:
`jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8888`

I then launched PuTTY and forwarded local port 8000 to remote port 8888, and navigated to localhost:8000/ from a browser on my local machine, but the browser says the site can't be reached.

This is the output of `sudo iptables -L` on my server:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Below is an excerpt of PuTTY's Event Log when I tried to connect to http://localhost:8000/ from my local machine

2018-06-06 21:12:58 Forwarded port closed due to local error: Network error: Software caused connection abort
2018-06-06 21:12:59    Forwarded port closed due to local error: Network error: Software caused connection abort
2018-06-06 21:13:48    Opening connection to XX.XX.XX.XXX:8888 for forwarding from [::1]:50416
2018-06-06 21:13:48 Opening connection to XX.XX.XX.XXX:8888 for forwarding from [::1]:50417
2018-06-06 21:15:56 Forwarded connection refused by server: Connect failed [Connection timed out]
2018-06-06 21:15:56    Forwarded connection refused by server: Connect failed [Connection timed out]
2018-06-06 21:15:56    Opening connection to XX.XX.XX.XXX:8888 for forwarding from [::1]:50456
2018-06-06 21:18:03 Forwarded connection refused by server: Connect failed [Connection timed out]
2018-06-06 21:18:03 Opening connection to XX.XX.XX.XXX:8888 for forwarding from [::1]:50488
2018-06-06 21:18:03 Opening connection to XX.XX.XX.XXX:8888 for forwarding from [::1]:50489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a clue here: https://superuser.com/questions/1212678/windows-10-putty-something-blocks-port-tunnel

I was forwarding local port 8000 to the **global** IP address of the server, when I should have been forwarding to **loopback** address 127.0.0.1. Making that change in the PuTTY connection configuration solved my problem.

I'm not sure why I can't forward to the global IP address, and if anyone can explain, I'd appreciate your input.